# SQL Syntax Error in Update Statement - Combining multiple fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Ok for the life of me I can't get this. I just haven't ever combined multiple fields and it's throwing me off as far as syntax goes. I know I'm supposed to single quote the |'s, but do I single quote the string fields? Where am I messing up here?

The error I get is simply "Syntax Error in Update Statement"

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblFinal SET (tblFinal.[Short Item Description] =
 & tblFinal.[2 Digit Year] & '|' & tblFinal.[License Type] & '|' 
 & trim(tblFinal.[License Number]) & '|' " & _
 "tblFinal.[State] & '|' & tblFinal.[City of Store])"
```

Comment: Shouldn't those single quotes around your pipes be double quotes?

Comment: Can you execute a select with that concatenation statement?

Comment: Since CurrentDB.Execute requires double quotes around the entire statement, I believe all inner string references are single quoted

The statement is able to compile, but upon trying to execute that line of code it gives me the Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Access, but I think you just have some errant double quotes in the mix:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblFinal SET tblFinal.[Short Item Description] = tblFinal.[2 Digit Year] & '|'& tblFinal.[License Type] & '|'& trim(tblFinal.[License Number]) & '|'& tblFinal.[State] & '|'& tblFinal.[City of Store]"
```

You just need single quotes around the literal text you're concatenating, and all fields can be concatenated with just `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Watch your line continuation characters and quotes:

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

sSQL = "UPDATE tblFinal SET (tblFinal.[Short Item Description] = " _
 & "tblFinal.[2 Digit Year] & '|' & tblFinal.[License Type] & '|' " _
 & "trim(tblFinal.[License Number]) & '|' " _
 & "tblFinal.[State] & '|' & tblFinal.[City of Store])"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailonError
```

It is nearly always best to create the SQL string first, it is much easier to debug. It is also best to use an instance of CurrentDb.

Comment: Could it all just be one line to avoid needing the continuation characters?